# Не сохраняет в файл txt почему?

Tags: python, instagram

Подскажите, почему не сохраняет в файл,  пользователей инстаграм.

```
for n in count(len(followers_count)):
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(n)

with open(f"{username}_followers_list.txt", "a") as followers_file:
    for link in followers_urls:
        followers_file.write(link + "\n")
```

А если этот код так, то сохраняет

```
for n in range(len(followers_count)):
```

А мне нужно, чтобы был бесконечный цикл и эта строка отлично справляется с этим

```
for n in count(len(followers_count)):
```

Comment: Ну да, у вас бесконечный цикл, до кода записи вход просто не доходит ход. А что вы хотели? Поместите код записи в файл внутрь бесконечного вашего цикла каким-то образом, и тогда он будет срабатывать.

Comment: Сделал, почему в файл записывается только 12строк?
Может как то по другому, прописать бесконечный цикл?, чтобы как надо записывал.

Comment: Для этого нужно понять, что у вас вообще в коде происходит. В цикле пополняется followers_urls?

Comment: @CrazyElf
Да верно. 'all_urls_div = followers_ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li") for url in all_urls_div: url = url.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href") followers_urls.append(url)'